# How to merge data frames only once per row

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

Apologies, I'm pretty new to all of this so please excuse any dumb questions I may ask.

I'm trying to merge a couple reports from salesforce using pandas,

I have two reports:

[Labour Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqhXs.png)
and [Plant Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnsnL.png)

and want to produce:  [Combined Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO64x.png)

I've tried merging, concatenating and aligning the dataframes, however, because the two share the same index, the first line from my plant report repeats 5 times ie:

[Incorrectly Merged Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYHEV.png)

My next thought is to use .align(), then .duplicated() to return a boolean series showing which rows are repeated, and clear the contents of the rows that are duplicated. If I was to use this method how might I be able to clear the contents of a row ?

Also this seems quite inefficient and difficult to do, are there any more elegant solutions ?

Cheers

Comment: Could you provide copy/pastable data that people can work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample data

labour-report.csv

```
DJR Number,Date,Foreman,Labour Name,Start,Finish,Hours Worked
1,1/01/2020,Emersen,Tai,6:30,15:00,8:30
1,1/01/2020,Emersen,Rachel,6:30,15:00,8:30
1,1/01/2020,Emersen,Andrew,6:30,15:00,8:30
1,1/01/2020,Emersen,Liam,6:30,15:00,8:30
2,2/01/2020,Scott,Rachel,6:30,15:00,8:30
3,3/01/2020,Michael,Andrew,6:30,15:00,8:30
```

plant-report.csv

```
DJR Number,Date,Foreman,Plant,Plant Hours
1,1/01/2020,Emersen,1,5
2,1/01/2020,Scott,2,5
3,1/01/2020,Michael,2,5
```

Below code can be used. The logic is to add an extra column to mark if the row needs to be joined or not. Then we can just do a left merge on pandas and then drop this extra column after the merge

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

labour_report = pd.read_csv('labour-report.csv')
plant_report = pd.read_csv('plant-report.csv')


should_join_row_lbr=[]
foremen  = {}
for index, labour_report_row in labour_report.iterrows():
    foreman = labour_report_row['Foreman']
    if foreman in foremen:
        should_join_row_lbr.append(0) # Dont join this row
    else:
        foremen[foreman]=1
        # Join this row as this is the first record for the foreman
        should_join_row_lbr.append(1) 
        labour_report['Should Join Row']=should_join_row_lbr

should_join_row_plnt = [1]*plant_report['DJR Number'].count()

plant_report['Should Join Row']=should_join_row_plnt

# Do a left join with Should Join column as well, 
# Only the records that have value 1 will be joined from labour_report
combined_report = pd.merge(labour_report,plant_report,on=['Foreman','Should Join Row'],how='left') 
combined_report = combined_report.drop(columns=['Should Join Row'])
combined_report = combined_report.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

print(combined_report)

combined_report.to_csv('combined_report.csv')
```

Should produce the result

```
   DJR Number_x     Date_x  Foreman Labour Name Start Finish Hours Worked DJR Number_y     Date_y Plant Plant Hours
0             1  1/01/2020  Emersen         Tai  6:30  15:00         8:30            1  1/01/2020     1           5
1             1  1/01/2020  Emersen      Rachel  6:30  15:00         8:30                                          
2             1  1/01/2020  Emersen      Andrew  6:30  15:00         8:30                                          
3             1  1/01/2020  Emersen        Liam  6:30  15:00         8:30                                          
4             2  2/01/2020    Scott      Rachel  6:30  15:00         8:30            2  1/01/2020     2           5
5             3  3/01/2020  Michael      Andrew  6:30  15:00         8:30            3  1/01/2020     2           5
```

Comment: Thank you mate !

Comment: @EmersenTamura-Paki If this works for you, please mark the answer as correct. If you need improvements, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: sorry man, for some reason I'm not given the option to select a correct answer. I think I'm too new to the site.

Comment: @EmersenTamura-Paki No problem, im glad the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you won't require a duplicate column of 'DJR Number' on your end result. We can join both Dataframe based on DJR Number. Duplicated function will return a series of Boolean about they're duplicated or not. If they're True, we assign null value to it.

```
merged = labour.merge(plant,on='DJR Number')
merged.loc[merged['DJR Number'].duplicated(),['Date_y','Foreman_y','Plant','Plant Hours']] = np.NaN
```

If you want even cleaner result, merged on three columns instead.

```
merged = labour.merge(plant,on=['DJR Number','Date','Foreman'])
merged.loc[merged['DJR Number'].duplicated(),['Plant','Plant Hours']] = np.NaN
```

This won't result in any duplicate column.

Please refer [Pandas Duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for documentation.